# Prestashop - insert tracking PHP file to footer

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I need to insert affiliate tracking file to footer in Prestashop 1.6 but I absolutely don't know how to :(

Integration guide tells this:

**Step 1. Include this php tracking file on any page you wish to track**

```
include('affiliate-pro/controller/affiliate-tracking.php');
```

Can someone tell me where to place this php code? What file in Prestashop 1.6 I have to edit?

And then there is step 2:

**Step 2. Once a sale has been completed (for example a thank you page) include the file to record the sale into Affiliate Pro**

```
$sale_amount = '21.98';
$product = 'My Product Description';
include('affiliate-pro/controller/record-sale.php');
```

Where should i place this code? What Prestashop file?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't they have a PrestaShop module? Search for `Affiliates Pro Module` and tell me if that's what you need, if not, you can use my method below

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a module, you can use the module generator [here](https://validator.prestashop.com/generator)

Name it "tracker", fill the description (min 20 characters), hit next twice then in the **Hooks** pick "**Footer**" & "**New orders**" and click "create"

In the backoffice modules page, install the module using the "Add a new module" button or extract the zip in "modules" folder of your installation

Next, you will need to modify the functions `hookDisplayFooter` & `hookActionValidateOrder`in the file "**tracker.php**" inside the module.

Here's the code to get you going:

```
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
{
    $products = $params['order']->product_list;
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $sale_amount = $product['total_wt'];
        $product = $product['name'];
        include('affiliate-pro/controller/record-sale.php');
    }
}

public function hookDisplayFooter()
{
    ob_start();
    include('test.php'); //use full path to your php file
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```